# TelegramBotClient" does not contain the definition of "StartReceiver"

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

In all tutorials, to start the bot, you need to start it using the StartReceiving() method, but for some reason, this method was not found

[image]

Comment: It was removed in https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/commit/6838acab629a67f351cb874fea9e138db6315a11. Looks like the tutorials you were reading are using an older ersion.

Answer (score 0):

Try install Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling package via Nuget. And add following line:

```
using Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling;
```

And yes, you refer to the old documentation. Now StartReceiving() have some parameters.